# Should we burn the tag "of"?

Tags: support, tags

I've been wandering through the tags, offering a wiki improvement here and there, when I came across the tag [of](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/of).

The tag was originally used for [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/63988/how-does-catholic-church-view-the-new-school-of-thought-on-multiplication-of-bre) where the individual tags [gospel](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel), [mark](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mark), [of](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/of) were listed — the OP apparently just typing along a series of keywords and not paying any attention to how the tags were being used or created (or even if they were the most relevant).

I updated the question (it's currently awaiting peer review), which was about a reference in the Gospel of Mark, to use the tag [gospel-of-mark](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gospel-of-mark), which has released the tag [of](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/of), which now has (after my edit has been peer reviewed) no associated questions.

I honestly can't think of a reason for the the [of](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/of) tag.  Would it be appropriate for the mods to remove it?

**EDIT:** Ditto the mispelled tag [catholicsm](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicsm) from [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64057/on-the-eucharist-and-human-digestion), which has been updated.

**EDIT:** Ditto the tag [body](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body), which currently has no associated questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, thanks for your efforts – keeping the place organized with tags is important but often tedious.

You are right that these tags are problematic.  However, in these cases, the appropriate course of action is to simply remove the unneeded tags via editing.  Once removed from all questions, they will be automatically deleted from the system without moderator intervention (see [What happens to old questions when a tag is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279921/300411)).

Moderators usually get involved when dealing with tag merges or creating tag synonyms, but we do that only when we think the tag is a good idea to keep around, but not as the "primary" tag for a particular topic.

Comment: THANKS!  I'm happy to not ask about orphaned tags.  Please note (in case the tree was lost in the forest) that I mentioned one tag that I recommend become a synonym: Chrism.

Comment: @JBH Hmm... that I'm less confident about. Is it a synonym of `charismatic` or `spiritual-gifts`? If the former, then it may not be needed at all, since `charismatic` will appear as an option when anyone types "charism." Probably worth addressing separately, to see what the tag creator intends and whether the community agrees that it is useful.

Comment: You're point's well taken.  I jumped to a conclusion based on the title of his question and apologize.  I looked up the [formal definition](https://www.google.com/search?ei=HAQzW46WF6fSjwSmrr3ICA&q=Chrism&oq=Chrism&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i71k1l8.0.0.0.106383.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.4vxdjU5YYoA) and it wouldn't be a synonym for the charismatic tag at all.  I'm going to remove that edit.  Hopefully the tag replacement I recommended for the question has been deleted (it hasn't processed).